# Google BigQuery; use subselect result in outer select; cross join

Tags: google-bigquery

I have query that results into one row table and I need to get this result in subsequent computation. Here is non working simplified example (just to depict what I'm trying to achieve):

```
SELECT amount / (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM [...]) FROM [...]
```

I tried some nested sub-selects and joins (cross join of the one row table with the other table) but didn't find any working solution. Is there a way to get this working in BigQuery?

Thanks, Radek

EDIT:

ok, I found solution:

```
select
  t1.x / t2.y as z
from
  (select 1 as k, amount as x from [...] limit 10) as t1
join
  (select 1 as k, sum(amount) as y from [...]) as t2
on
  t1.k = t2.k;
```

but not sure if this is the best how to do it...

Comment: check ratio_to_report(), example in answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the recently announced ratio_to_report() window function:

```
 SELECT RATIO_TO_REPORT(amount) OVER() AS z
 FROM [...]
```

`ratio_to_report` takes the `amount`, and divides it by the sum of all the result rows `amount`s.

Comment: yep, they have added bunch of useful functions recently

Answer (score 0):

The way you've found (essentially a cross join using a dummy key) is the best way I know of to do this query. We've thought about adding an explicit cross join operator to make it easier to see how to do this, but cross join can get expensive if not done correctly (e.g. if done on two large tables can create n^2 results).